# VIM installation on OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion can't be found on ~/.vim/

Tags: vim, terminal, macvim, sparkup

I'm pretty new on OS X and VIM, and I just tried to install **MacVim** (I downloaded snapshot 66 from github, which is actually build 7.3.754).

The problem is that when I was trying to install Sparkup (https://github.com/rstacruz/sparkup), I found that the installation folder is not on `~/.vim/`

I tried this on Terminal:

```
ls ~/.vim/
```

but it always returned `ls: /Users/andreoentoro/.vim: No such file or directory`

Any insights on what I do wrong here? I'm not really used to terminal though I am pretty good at working on DOS command, but it's totally different.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This folder, its subfolders (like `plugin`, `doc`, etc.) and your `~/.vimrc` are not created by Vim. You must create them yourself:

```
$ cd
$ mkdir .vim
$ touch .vimrc
```

Here is what you should get if you follow the plugin's instructions:

```
/Users/andreoentoro/.vim
   |-after
   |---plugin
   |-----snipMate.vim
   |-autoload
   |---snipMate.vim
   |-doc
   |---snipMate.txt
   |-ftplugin
   |---html_snip_helper.vim
   |-plugin
   |---snipMate.vim
   |-snippets
   |---(many files)
   |-syntax
   |---snippet.vim
```

Just copying `ftplugin` won't be enough.

Comment: Thanks for this, but it still doesn't work -- I had copied a directory using cp -R ftplugin ~/.vim/ but it's still not working.

The one that's not working is the sparkup plugin on VIM, the VIM itself works fine.

Comment: Yes, neither `~/.vim/` nor `~/.vimrc` are needed for Vim to work properly. Copying `ftplugin` is not enough to install SnipMate. See my edit.